# choose which extensions do not encrypt

Tags: c#

I'm working in school project, encrypter tool, in short words this is the function caller

```
foreach (string file in files)
{      
   var validExtensions = new[]
   {
      ".txt"
   };
   string extension = Path.GetExtension(abc);
   if (validExtensions.Contains(extension))
   {  
      EncryptFile(file, password);
   }
}
```

this code will encrypt only the txt files, but I need to do the reverse, I need to set what type of extensions the program will not encrypt, like `.dat` files are important for windows, if someone using my program encrypt it, the windows crash and never boot up (unless in safe mode).

Comment: What about just sticking a boolean NOT in your `if` statement?

Comment: Simple, rather than keeping valid extension; maintain "escape extension list/array" and in `if` check with `!`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach (string file in files)
{ 
   var escapeExtensions = new[] { ".dat" };
   string extension =Path.GetExtension(abc);
   if(!escapeExtensions.Contains(extension))
   { 
      EncryptFile(file, password); 
   }
}
```